# jQuery Variable Addition and other Sums

Tags: jquery, variables, global-variables

I have javascript which counts seperately every time 2 seperate buttons are clicked, this then outputs the amount on the same page. This works, however I am now trying to add a third value to output on the page which is the total of the clicks which i would calculate by adding the 2 attributes together. This just doesn't seem to be working though.

java

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var NextClick = 0;
var PrevClick = 0;
var TotalClicks = 0;

function getValueNext()
  {
  var y=document.getElementById("NextClick").value = ++NextClick
  $('.NextClick').val(y);
  }

function getValuePrev()
  {
  var x=document.getElementById("PrevClick").value = ++PrevClick
  $('.PrevClick').val(x);
  }

function getSumClicks()
  {
  var z= x + y
  $('.TotalClicks').val(z);
  }

</script>
```

Html

```
  Clicked next <input class="NextClick" size="3" onfocus="this.blur();" value="0"> times.
  Clicked prev <input class="PrevClick" size="3" onfocus="this.blur();" value="0"> times.
  Clicked total <input class="TotalClicks" size="3" onfocus="this.blur();" value="0">      times.
```

The point of this is that from the clicks on each button I can work out which image they were left on and so which they have selected.

It has also just occured to me that instead of recording two values I could instead have a function that adds one when next is clicked, but takes one away when prev is clicked, im not sure how to code this though.

Comment: Could you do a mock up in http://jsfiddle.net?  Also, javascript has function level scope, so your `getSumClicks()` will not have access to `x` and `y` as your code is.  You'd have to move them up to where `NextClick` and the others are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an element with `NextClick` as the ID. So this:

```
var y=document.getElementById("NextClick").value = ++NextClick
```

Becomes:

```
var y = ++NextClick
```

Second x and y are local variables to their functions. They don't exist inside of `getSumClicks()`.

You probably want this:

```
function getValueNext() {
  $('.NextClick').val(++NextClick);
}

function getValuePrev() {
  $('.PrevClick').val(++PrevClick);
}

function getSumClicks() {
  $('.TotalClicks').val(NextClick + PrevClick);
}
```